# Divide a subset of data table values by a number

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table similar to below

```
dt <- data.table(Name = c("m","v","v","d","t","y","f"),
            id = c("a","A",1,2,NA,2,NA),
             val = c("b","B",30,10,20,NA,10))
```

I like to divide all numeric values by 5. I get an error when I try this because of NA values in some rows.

```
dt[3:.N,-1] <- dt[3:.N,-1]/5
```

Answer (score 2):

A column can have data of only a single type. So although `id` and `val` has numbers in it they are still converted to character because of the values in first 2 rows.

```
dt$id
#[1] "a" "A" "1" "2" NA  "2" NA 

str(dt)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Name: chr  "m" "v" "v" "d" ...
# $ id  : chr  "a" "A" "1" "2" ...
# $ val : chr  "b" "B" "30" "10" ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

The quotes around the numbers "1", "2" indicate that the numbers are stored as characters and using `str` confirms the same.

If we want to do any mathematical operation on this numbers we first need to change them to numeric. Here's a function that will change numbers to numeric and divide by 5. If it is not numeric, we keep the value as it is which will help to maintain the first 2 values.

```
library(data.table)

divide_by_5 <- function(x) {
  suppressWarnings(ifelse(grepl('^\\d+$', x), as.numeric(x)/5, x))
}


cols <- names(dt)[-1]
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, divide_by_5), .SDcols = cols]
dt

#   Name   id  val
#1:    m    a    b
#2:    v    A    B
#3:    v  0.2    6
#4:    d  0.4    2
#5:    t <NA>    4
#6:    y  0.4 <NA>
#7:    f <NA>    2
```

---

To divide the specific values by 5 you can use this improved function.

```
divide_by_5 <- function(x, inds) {
  x[inds] <- as.numeric(x[inds])/5
  x
}

cols <- names(dt)[-1]
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, divide_by_5, c(3, 4, 6)), .SDcols = cols]
dt
```

Comment: thanks, what if I know what rows need to be divided by  5. say I want to divide values of rows 3,4,6 only. @ronak shah

Comment: @ZackFara They are still going to be character values.